# Finding last rows in three(3) separate sheets. VBA Excel 2007

Tags: excel, row, excel-2007, type-mismatch, vba

I've been trying to write some codes for copying and inserting data between sheets on excel. And part of this process involves finding the last row or 2nd to last row of each of the three sheets. But after finding the last row in the first sheet, and after activating the 2nd sheet, the program keeps giving me an Error 13: type mismatch error. How should I resolve this problem??

```
  Sub DeleteRow()

 Dim StartRow, Lastrow2, NuRow As Long
StartRow = 3
 Dim LastColumn As Long
 Dim LastRow As Long
 Dim LastCell As Long

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    'Search for any entry, by searching backwards by Rows.

LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows,  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

NuRow = LastRow - 1
Range(StartRow & ":" & NuRow).Select
Rows(StartRow & ":" & NuRow).Delete

Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Range(1 & ":" & LastRow).Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown



    'Delete first two and last lines

Range("A1").Select
Rows("1:2").Delete
Range("A65536").End(xlUp).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp

Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
'Error 13: Type Mismatch -->Lastrow2 = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is some code based on my interpretation of what you are trying to do.  You don't need to select cells to work with them and 99.9% of the time you really shouldn't.

```
Dim StartRow As Long

StartRow = 3

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    .Rows(StartRow & ":" & LastRow - 1).Delete
End With

With Sheets("Sheet2")
    LastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    .Rows(1).Resize(LastRow).Copy
    .Rows(1).Resize(LastRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown

    .Rows("1:2").Delete

    .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End With
```

Also when dimensioning variables you should dimension like this:

```
Dim StartRow as long, Lastrow2 as long, NuRow As Long
```

In your orginal code as you have only dimensioned the last variable, startrow and lastrow2 will be variant datatypes not long.

Comment: Sorry I lost my internet connection last night half way though trying to edit my post.   It should make more sense now.  Don't forget to mark one of your solutions as an answer if suitable, otherwise people will neglect to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have contiguous data, you can use CurrentRegion, or if you know you have data all the way down in e.g. Col A, then use

```
lrow = Range("A65000").end(xlup).row
```

to find the last row.